# Set width to 100% (fill container) with pandas set_table_styles

Tags: python, css, pandas

Context: I have the following dataframe that I'm applying several stylying steps to then transform into HTML and display it in a web page.

The dataframe and styles being applied:

```
th_props = [
  ('font-size', '14px'),
  ('text-align', 'left'),
  ('font-weight', 'bold'),
  ('color', '#6d6d6d'),
  ('background-color', '#eeeeef'),
  ('border','1px solid #eeeeef'),
  #('padding','12px 35px')
]

td_props = [
  ('font-size', '14px'),
  ('text-align', 'center'),
  #('width','100%')

]

cell_hover_props = [  # for row hover use <tr> instead of <td>
    ('background-color', '#eeeeef')
]

headers_props = [
    ('text-align','center'),
    ('font-size','1em')
]
#dict(selector='th:not(.index_name)',props=headers_props)

table_props = [
    ('width','100%')
]
#dict(selector='table',props=table_props),


styles = [
    dict(selector="th", props=th_props),
    dict(selector="td", props=td_props),
    dict(selector="td:hover",props=cell_hover_props),
    # dict(selector='th.col_heading',props=headers_props),
    dict(selector='th.col_heading.level0',props=headers_props),
    dict(selector='th.col_heading.level1',props=td_props),

]


    arrays = [
        ["bar", "bar", "baz", "baz", "foo", "foo", "qux", "qux"],
        ["one", "two", "one", "two", "one", "two", "one", "two"],
    ]
    tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
    
    index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=[None, "Brand"])
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3, 8), index=["A", "B", "C"], columns=index)

st.markdown(df.style.set_table_styles(styles).to_html(),unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

Which gives me this dataframe when rendered to a webpage:
[image]

As you can see, the table doesn't extend thourgh the whole container. How can I set the width of the table to 100%?

Attempts:

I've tried editting the `th_props` and `td_props` adding `('width','100%')` as such:

```
td_props = [
  ('font-size', '14px'),
  ('text-align', 'center'),
  ('width','100%')
```

But I get things like this:

[image]

Which selector and property should I use in set_table_styles in pandas to get something like this:

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: In `table_props ` if you change the width from `100%` to `100vw` what happens?

Comment: That's it! Thank you for your help, feel free to add it as an answer so I can then approve it :) Simple, but might help someone else (I had no idea 100vw even existed as a property)

Comment: Sounds good, I will add an answer thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing `100%` to `100vw` in `table_props`  And if that causes some issues such as overflow you can do something like `95vw` or something as well.

1 more thing you can try if its still a little weird is change `100vw` back to `100%` in `table_props` and then try adding `100vw`  to the `width` in `td_props` and that might solve your issue as well.

Comment: Great. Can we set the width of each column manually ? The '100%'  seems to shrink certain columns too much, without utilizing the free spaces in the other columns