# Set table width with pandas set_table_styles

Tags: python, html, css, django, pandas

I'm trying to set the table width using set_table_styles, but it doesn't work. I tried to find information about this in the documentation, but there is no example there.
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/style.html

I looked into this issue, but it didn't help either.
[Set width to 100% (fill container) with pandas set_table_styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74046791/set-width-to-100-fill-container-with-pandas-set-table-styles)

Part of my code:

```
turnover = pd.pivot_table(data_for_turnover, columns=['Date'], values=['Turnover', 'Sales', 'Stocks'], aggfunc='sum')
table_style = {'selector': 'table','props': [('width', '100%')]}
turnover = turnover.style.format('{:.0f}')
turnover.set_table_styles([table_style]).to_html()
```

Next I display using Django, but the width (I also tried change border, margin) does not change. If I try to change the th or td styles, they are applied. Please help me find, if not a solution, then a reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you need to set a fixed [`width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width) of an html table, you should use [pixels](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CSS_pixel) rather then `%`s.

```
table_style = {
    # adjust the selectors if needed
    "selector": "th.col_heading,td",
    "props": [
        ("width", "100px"), # px instead of %
        ("text-align", "center"), # optional ?
    ]
}

(
    turnover.style
        .format(precision=0)
        .set_table_styles([table_style])
        # .to_html() # uncomment to make an html
)
```

Output (*in Jupyter*) :

[image]

Used input (*to mock your* `pivot_table`):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)

turnover = pd.DataFrame(
    data=np.random.uniform(1, 1000, 12).reshape(3, 4),
    index=["Turnover", "Sales", "Stocks"],
    columns=["January", "February", "March", "April"]
)

print(turnover)

             January    February       March       April
Turnover  417.604983  720.604169    1.114260  303.030240
Sales     147.609135   93.246256  187.073951  346.215166
Stocks    397.370707  539.277917  419.775320  685.534281
```

Comment: thanks, this helped me solve the problem! Also I found out a similar solution:
`table_style = {'selector': '','props': [('width', '100%')],}`
This could mean that the empty selector is applied to the entire table. Thank you!